# To print PDF in the slot of 5

Tags: java

This is the sample code that I have written

```
public class hello {
    static int startLine=1;
    static int endLine=6;
    static int k=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello pd = new hello();
        do {
            pd.printPDF();
        } while(!(k <= endLine));

    }

    public void printPDF() {
        for(int count=0;count<5;count++) {
            System.out.println("The value of count....."+count);
            k++;
            System.out.println("value of k....."+k);
        }
    }
}
```

If I have start date as 8 SEP and End Date is 23 August. In between I have 6 PDF to print but I have to print those PDF in the slot of five so the counter I have set is 5. Then the remaining is 6th PDF and in the next slot it should print only 6th PDF because we have total 6 PDF to print. However it is printing PDF again in the slot of 5, so can someone tell me the condition that I need to change in while or need to take something else?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider the following:

- From the Java convention, the class names should be in CamelCase (use `Hello.java` rather than `hello.java`).
- The variables within a class should be `private` to prevent other classes from accessing it. The default value is `package protected` with is not required in this scenario.
- As you are using `static` variables you could also use `static` methods to avoid the class instantiation (the `new Hello`) is not required.
- Consider moving the creation of variable `k` to the method since its is smallest scope.
- You could use a `for` construction or a `while` loop but I don't think a `do while` is required since you need to loop over all the PDFs you need to generate and if there are no PDFs to generate you don't need to do anything.
- To make the last PDF have a different extension you need to pass the current date (`i`) and the `END` date to the `printPDF` method so you can compute the real amount of entries to process on that PDF.

Taking all this considerations into account, I here provide you the code:

```
public class Hello {

    private static int startLine = 1;
    private static int endLine = 6;
    private static int SLOT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Loop over the number of PDFs to generate
        int i = startLine;
        while (i <= endLine) {
            printPDF(i, endLine);
            ++i;
        };
        // Alternatively you could use a for construction
        // for (int i = startLine; i <= endLine; ++i) {
        //    printPDF();
        // };
    }

    public static void printPDF(int current, int end) {
        // Regular PDF slot size
        int currentSlot = SLOT;
        if (current == end) {
            // Slot size for the last entry
            currentSlot = 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Treating PDF " + current);
        for (int count = 0; count < currentSlot; count++) {
            System.out.println("- The value of count....." + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I want to print 5 PDF in a count of 5 like PDF1,PDF2,..PDF5 and the 6th should be in diff slot PDF6

Comment: Please edit your question define more accurately what do you mean by slot because you are talking about dates but your code only uses lines.

Comment: @NehaBali if this solution helped you please consider Accepting it or post your own solution so that others can benefit from the question.